# Inserting Large XML Document in Sql Server with TIBCO Designer

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, tibco

I'm trying insert a large xml document (about 10MB) into a Sql Server 2008 table, this document is built in run-time.

My problem is a better way to make this insert.
I'm using a simple insert command with one parameter of type string, but dosen´t work. In the table the field is showing a NULL value.

Unfortunately I'm not using any programming language, this is a project built in TIBCO Desginer, but I can use pieces of Java code.

Has some way to do this with a single insert?

Comment: Did you try to stream the data? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setAsciiStream(int, java.io.InputStream)

Comment: please provide the input mapping to your JDBC Update Activity (Ctrl-C root of the input mapping will put the underlying XSLT on to the clipboard, which you can then paste into your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the XML to a string first, either by using XPath as below or by using the Render XML activity.

```
tib:render-xml(//path)
```